# Run code on start with javaFX 2

Tags: javafx

I would like to know how I can run code with the start of JavaFX 2 applications.
For example the Hello World application in Netbeans. How can I set elements invisible on start?
I use JavaFx with FXML and SceneBuilder.

With java I could just use "edit code" in Netbeans to put my code in and it would run on start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With fxml you can attach a [controller](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers) whose initialize method is invoked when the document is loaded (this would be the preferred way for me to initialize fxml based UIs in code).

JavaFX applications have a [start](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html#start%28javafx.stage.Stage%29) method for processing initializing the GUI on startup.

In your fxml you can set the visibility property on a Node to define it's initial visible state.

You can create a CSS stylesheet and in that setup a selector which selects your node and does initial styling on it such as making it invisible.

FXML also allows you to embed scripting languages in the fxml document or external files which can be used to initialize the GUI and act on events.